# write StackId to S3 using Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

Im using create_stack api using AWS Lambda(with nested stack)..but i would like to store each stack Id in S3 which is created as part of nested stack.
Im using python for Lambda function.

Whenever a individual stack is created as part of nested stack(cloudformation) it appends each stack with unique Id as below

MYnestedStack-Ec2Stack-1WQDHSJFIFNFN

i want to store this value in S3 bucket so that i can use that Id to delete the stack without manually going to AWS cloudformation console to delete the same..

I have tried as suggested by @ataylor below but im getting error

**"An error occurred during JSON serialization of response: datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 12, 15, 23, 16, 451000, tzinfo=tzlocal()) is not JSON serializable"**

```
import boto3
import time
import json

client = boto3.client('cloudformation')


response = client.describe_stack_resources(
    StackName='Mystack',
    LogicalResourceId='Ec2Stack'
)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
        return response
```

I have also tried below code and getting error as

**"An error occurred during JSON serialization of response: cloudformation.StackResource(stack_name='Mystack', logical_id='Ec2Stack') is not JSON serializable"**

```
import boto3
import time
import json

cloudformation = boto3.resource('cloudformation')
stack_resource = cloudformation.StackResource('prodUpgradeForchestartorFullStack','ApplicationStack')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
        return stack_resource
```

Please Suggest!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the stack name from the CloudFormation API.  In particular, if your parent stack is called `Ec2Stack`, you can get the name of the nested stacks from the command line with:

```
aws cloudformation describe-stack-resources \
    --query StackResources[].[PhysicalResourceId][] \
    --stack-name Ec2Stack
```

If you have the logical ID and want the physical ID of a resource, use:

```
aws cloudformation describe-stack-resources \
    --query 'StackResources[?LogicalResourceId==`MYnestedStack`].[PhysicalResourceId][]' \
    --stack-name Ec2Stack
```

You can call the same API from python: http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/cloudformation.html#stackresource.

You can use it directly from the API when you want to delete the stack, or save it to S3.

Comment: import boto3
import time
client = boto3.client('cloudformation')
response = client.describe_stack_resources(
    StackName='Mystack',
    LogicalResourceId='AppStack'
)     
def lambda_handler(event, context):
              return response                                                                                                 Im getting below error                                                                                    An error occurred during JSON serialization of response: datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 12, 15, 23, 16, 451000, tzinfo=tzlocal()) is not JSON serializable